# Pipe redirection fails on pre/post-build steps in the Code::Blocks

Tags: linux, shell, build, codeblocks

I'm trying to do the following on the post-build step (Build Options... / Pre/post build steps) in the Code::Blocks 16.01 (Build: Feb2 2016, 03:15:41 - wx2.8.12 (Linux,unicode) - 64 bit):

`` PYMODULE="`printf ${PROJECT_NAME}.so | sed 's/^lib/_/'`" ``

But it fails showing in the *Build log*:

`` s/^lib/_/'`"': 1: s/^lib/_/'`"': Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution ``

Then I tried

`echo libdaoc.so | sed 's/^lib/_/'`

which works fine in the terminal, but in the Code::Blocks pre/post build step, the pipe operation fails showing in the *Build log*:

`echo libdaoc.so | sed 's/^lib/_/'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...
  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
...`

How to make it work?
Essentially I'm trying to make builds from the Code::Blocks environment and then export via cbp2make, so I need to use environment variables instead of the hardcoded fixed names.

Comment: Please clarify if the string "*lib*" is known to always be a prefix of whatever's in `${PROJECT_NAME}`.

Comment: Yes, "lib" is a predefined string. Thanks a lot, agc, your solution fixed the issue! I did not know about such parameters expansion!

Comment: The solution works for the shell. But as it found Code::Blocks pre/post build panel does not support most of the shell commands and yields "_libdaoc#lib}"... It's a shame for the Code::Blocks...

Answer (score 1):

No need for `sed`, any *POSIX* shell can do the same job using parameter substitution:

```
PYMODULE="_${PROJECT_NAME#lib}.so"
```

The above assumes the prefix "*lib*" exists, (the OP seems to imply it should).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Code::Blocks [script expansion](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Variable_expansion#Script_expansion) for the interactive build and solution provided by @agc for the Makefile... Basically, the Makefile requires some postprocessing after being generated by the `cb2make`:

- Replacement of the *Code::Blocks script expansion* with the standard shell commands
- Specification of the Global Variables defined in the Code::Blocks (manually specified variables, PROJECT_NAME, etc. are not exported)

I had higher expectations from *cb2make* and *Code::Blocks*. Trying to make a cross-platform solution they lost ability to perform adequate builds even on a single platform.